# django-tinymce working with django-admin but not working in form template

Tags: python, django, tinymce-4

in django admin django-tinymce is working but in template tinymce widget is not working. Please provide a solution

[django model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyH3C.png)

my model.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
nameuser = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
contents = tinymce.HTMLField(blank=True,null=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)
```

form.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ('title','contents','tags')
    
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Title'})
    self.fields['tags'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

my views.py

```
def createQue(request):
User = request.user
form=QuestionForm()
if request.method =='POST':
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        blog = form.save(commit=False)
        blog.author=User
        blog.save()
        return redirect('home')
context={'form':form}
return render(request,'blog_form.html',context)
```

my template file

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %} {% for field in form %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

in temlate it show only blank form-control

[template view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDD0y.png)

Comment: How are you rendering the form in your template?

Answer (score 0):

I try all the method but not working so alternatively I used ckeditor as RichTexteditor and it worked for admin and template
follow the document of ckeditor it work fine properly for me

Comment: Please include the full set of code you used to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this is because you are not passing `{{ form.media }}` in your template. Mine was because I didn't add it like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```